# Read annotation from XSD by element XPath

Tags: java, xml, validation, xpath, xsd

I have XML document builded by XSD. Each element in XSD with annotation.
When i validate XML by XSD i can generate an XPath of error (using Stack), how can i read annotation from XSD with XPath of element?

i am using XSOM for read XSD schema.

Comment: Why don't you just run an XPath expression against the XSD ? Why XSOM ?